# Issues displaying a table view cell from one view controller to another

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

Right now I am trying to move information from my goal cell into a new table view cell, and am having difficulty getting the cell to display.

Here is the code for my goal cell.

```
import UIKit

    class GoalsViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var Goals: [String] = ["goal 1", "goal 2", "goal 3"]
    let theEmptyModel: [String] = ["No data in this section."]
    var valueToPass = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    func showGoalSelected() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now()) {
            let popUp = GoalSelectedPopUp()
            self.view.addSubview(popUp)
        }
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "GoalConversationsCell_1") {
            let viewController = segue.destination as! ActiveGoalsViewController
            viewController.Goals.append([valueToPass])
            }    
       }

}

extension GoalsViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return Goals.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "GoalCell_1", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = Goals[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 3
        return cell
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            valueToPass = Goals[indexPath.row]
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "activeGoalsSegue", sender: self)
        Goals.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        if Goals.count != 0 {
            showGoalSelected()
        } else {
            Goals.append(contentsOf: theEmptyModel)
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Here is the goal cells storyboard with the push segue connecting it to the other table view.

[image: goal table view with connection of a push segue]

That other table view is shown below. 
[image: other table view in which I am trying to send the cell]

Here is the code for this new tableview.

```
import UIKit

class ActiveGoalsViewController: UIViewController {

     @IBOutlet weak var goalTableView: UITableView!

     let sections: [String] = ["Mark as Complete:", "History:"]
     var goals: [[String]] = [[], []]
     let theEmptyModel: [String] = ["No data in this section."]

extension ActiveGoalsViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return Goals[section].count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TodayGoalViewCell_1", for: indexPath) as? GoalTableViewCell
            cell?.goalLabel.text = Goals[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
            cell?.cellDelegate = self
            cell?.index = indexPath
            return cell!
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return sections[section]
    }


    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return Goals.count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {


            if Goals[0] != theEmptyModel {
               Goals[1].append(Goals[0][indexPath.row])
                if Goals[1].first!.contains("No data in this section.") {
                    Goals[1].removeFirst()
                }
                Goals[0].remove(at: indexPath.row)
                if Goals[0].count == 0 {
                    Goals[0].append(contentsOf: theEmptyModel)
                }
                tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
      }
```

Once the goal is selected, it sends me to the new storyboard, but this new view does not display the goal that was just added. Can someone help me figure out why this isn't working? Thanks.

Comment: I don't see tableView data source or delegate set in `ActiveGoalsViewController`

Answer (score 1):

I think in the second view controller you need to access the "goals" variable with a lower case g rather then the "Goals" variable with an upper case G.